# Is it possible to build a Standalone Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to build a Vue app, which does not require Vue as as a dependency at runtime?

I.e. instead of the browser having to load the vue.js and the app like this

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.myxyzhost.com/my-app.js"></script>
```

have a my-app.js which already includes vue.js, so that including the script in a web page becomes a simple one liner?

```
<script src="https://www.myxyzhost.com/my-app.js"></script>
```

Comment: maybe you prefer static site generation? You might want to look at Nuxt

Comment: This is called bundling. Tools like webpack and grunt do this.

Comment: @A.Lau Nope, why static, when I need a dynamic component?

Comment: @nurettin I _am_ using Webpack. But that doesn't solve the problem, since – (quote from the Vue docs):

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component

"Note on Vue Dependency

In web component mode, Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. The bundle will assume Vue is available on the host page as a global variable."

Comment: You're referring to docs for web component mode. Use the default app mode and vue will be included in the bundle.

Comment: @LongHike why did you choose the web component target?

Comment: @nurettin It seemed to be the closest to what I actually need.

Answer (score 2):

So, it was actually simpler than I thought:

I just created a separate entry file for webpack to consume like

```
my-custom-component-entry.js
```

and slammed everything I needed in there (vue and the respective component):

```
// This is the actual solution, I was looking for.
import Vue from 'vue';
import MyCustomComponent from './components/my-custom-component.vue'; 

new Vue({
  components: {
    'my-custom-component': MyCustomComponent
  } 
}).$mount('#app'); // ya gotta have a #app element somewhere of course
```

And then I built it with webpack (I am not going into detail here).

Now everything is packed in on file. No separate Vue runtime, which a customer might need to install. All that's necessary is:

```
<script src="https://www.myxyzhost.com/dist/my-custom-component.js"></script>
```

And yes, as always, this screws up, if you don't add the proper polyfills for internet explorer, but I take that for granted.

The important thing: for modern browsers it's a one liner which makes it easier to sell. That was all I needed.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the source code of implementation of your answer?