# How use multiple Vue instances and single file components (in my Drupal theme) correctly

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, drupal-8

I want to enhance the UI of my (Drupal) theme with Vue.js for some sections, functionality and components. Vue is loaded and build (Webpack) correctly.

In my `page.html.twig` file (Drupal's main page template file) I trigger Vue by:

```
<div id="app">
```

Then I have the following structure:

From **`index.js`** I am importing `Vue` and `App.vue`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

From **`App.vue`** I want to import and controle all of my (child) components like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      HelloWorld
    }
  }
</script>

<style></style>
```

Now I am facing a problem because I have one Vue instance `<div id="app">`.

But in e.g. `header.html.twig` I need another Vue instance and import some other Single file components here.

How do I make use of multiple Vue instances and be able to work with Single file components?

And is my approach correctly?

Comment: How are you including the compiled javascript? Why would you want to use vue.js for a menu? Seems like something easily done with css. I am not sure if vue.js can be easily compiled out to components, but I know svelte can.

Comment: @2pha I am building an interactive hamburger menu. With an `onclick` event on the button. It's just a small part/functionality of the site. There will become more. The compiled `main.bundle.js` file is included by my Drupal theme.

Comment: @2pha From `index.js` I am adding Vue.js library by adding `import Vue from 'vue'`. So than Vue is added isn't it?

Comment: take note of this line `$mount('#app')`, so you are going to need a `app` id on an element somewhere. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113321/is-it-possible-to-build-a-standalone-vue-app) is a very similar question